# ArrayList elements changed to last entry every time

Tags: android

I have the class such as below . when I run it , it should save x and y that touched on screen positions for making circles in circles ArrayList every time I touch . but at every time all elements of array list have been last x,y ( all elements changed to last element) . what should I do ?

```
package com.siamak.rain.ball;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class Balls extends ImageView {

    static ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    static Paint             cp;


    public Balls(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initial();
    }


    public Balls(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initial();
    }


    public Balls(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initial();
    }


    public static class Circle {

        static float x;
        static float y;
    }


    public static void initial() {
        cp = new Paint();
        cp.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        cp.setAntiAlias(true);
        cp.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        cp.setStrokeWidth(5);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                Circle c = new Circle();
                c.x = event.getX();
                c.y = event.getY();
                circles.add(c);
                invalidate();
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (Circle c: circles)
            canvas.drawCircle(c.x, c.y, 50, cp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't make the variables within `Circle` static!

Comment: Because `Circle` class and variables are  `static` . to get desire behavior remove `static ` from class and variables